# How to Export the CSV in MongoDB with out giving any fields

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I have a collection where it has many fields, from that i have to export the CSV with all the fields.
As of now i am using the below command to export the CSV file.

**mongoexport --db test --host 172.00.00.000 --port 97027 -c RdMergeData --type csv  --fields name,phone,group --out /Users/macair/data.csv**

With the above command i have to use the field names always when i want to export an CSV, in my data i have many fields where i cannot type all those field names every time.
How can we export an CSV with all the fields without typing the field names manually in the command.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you must specify the field list when exporting to CSV.  If you want to export to JSON instead, you do not have to specify the field list.

You can use a file to specify the fields to export, which may be easier for you as you can create the file once and then reuse it for multiple exports.

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#export-in-csv-format for more details.